# Assert types when calling javascript compiled from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using a library, compiled from Typescript to Javascript in my Javascript project.

The method signatures in the Typescript API use typed method arguments.

This type information is lost in the compiled Javascript artifact.

I am aware, that types are a core feature of Typescript. Is it possible, to ensure type safety when calling the Javascript library from a Javascript project? For example using *types.d.ts* and a static code analysis tool.

**Edit**:
The question marked as duplicate is the other way around. In my case it is:

```
TS library -(compile/bundle)-> JS artifact
JS project -(require)-> JS artifact
```

The question referred as duplicate has the following usecase:

```
TS project -(require)-> JS file with types.d.ts
```